# Drupal7 import data from other database

Tags: drupal, import

I am new in drupal development and want to import data from other database.database structure is (id,name and image) image field have image path now i want to all data into drupal as it is. Also suggest me which type is perfect for this type structure(taxonomy or content type).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module.